# FBSDKLoginKit freezes App after Login on iPad with iOS 10.x

Tags: ios, ios10, fbsdkloginkit

I have a problem that after a successful login on iPads with iOS 10.x, the app freezes. The problem does not occur on iOS 11.x, I'm able to reproduce this behaviour in simulator as well as on real devices. Updated to version `4.34.0`, didn't solve the issue.

Anyone else experiencing this? Someone found a solution?

Comment: Can you show piece of code?

Comment: can you show the openURL code to us?

Comment: doesn't you get the answer yet?

Answer (score 0):

I faced after successful login it doesn't returning any values and not get back the user to the app. One Possible way is this. (change your openURL code with)

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

    let appname:String = options.first?.value as! String
    print(appname)
    if appname == "com.facebook.Facebook" {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(
            app,
            open: url as URL!,
            sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String,
            annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]
        )
    }
    return Twitter.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options)
}
```

Second Method for other iOS versions (iOS 10).

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
 return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(
  application,
  open: url as URL!,
  sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
  annotation: annotation)
}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

[This Facebook SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-swift) work for me.